# Mutating column to dataframe using apply function by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I am trying to use the apply function to rows within a grouped dataframe to check for the existence of other rows within that group that match certain conditions dependent on each row. I am able to get this to work for one group but not for all.

For example, with no grouping:

```
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
station <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2)
timeslot <- c(13, 14, 20, 21, 24, 23, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16)

df <- data.frame(id, station, timeslot)

s <- 2

df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(id == 1) %>% 
  arrange(id, timeslot) %>% 
  mutate(match = ifelse(station == s, apply(., 1, function(x) (any(as.numeric(x[3] + 1) == .$timeslot))), FALSE))

  id station timeslot match
1  1       1       13 FALSE
2  1       2       14 FALSE
3  1       3       20 FALSE
4  1       3       21 FALSE
5  1       2       23  TRUE
6  1       2       24 FALSE
```

In the above code, for each station 2 row, I am trying to check all other rows to see if there exists a timeslot with a value of one greater (for any station). This works as expected.

Then, I go on to apply this to a grouped dataframe:

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, timeslot) %>% 
  mutate(match = ifelse(station == s, apply(., 1, function(x) (any(as.numeric(x[3] + 1) == .$timeslot))), FALSE))


      id station timeslot match
   <int>   <int>    <int> <lgl>
 1     1       1       13 FALSE
 2     1       2       14 TRUE 
 3     1       3       20 FALSE
 4     1       3       21 FALSE
 5     1       2       23 TRUE 
 6     1       2       24 FALSE
 7     2       1        8 FALSE
 8     2       1        9 FALSE
 9     2       3       10 FALSE
10     2       2       15 FALSE
11     2       2       16 TRUE
```

and get some unwanted results. It seems like it is not applied by group and I can't figure out how to fix this. How can I apply this function so that only the other rows within a group are checked? In reality, my dataset is much bigger and the conditions are more complex, so it is not running quickly either.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I should add that I have also tried a solution using the arrange() and lead() function but since some timeslot values are shared by many stations in my larger dataset I could not get this to work

Comment: Thanks I have added this in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, timeslot) %>% 
  mutate(match = station == s & ((timeslot + 1) %in% timeslot))
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
# # Groups:   id [2]
#       id station timeslot match
#    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>
#  1     1       1       13 FALSE
#  2     1       2       14 FALSE
#  3     1       3       20 FALSE
#  4     1       3       21 FALSE
#  5     1       2       23 TRUE 
#  6     1       2       24 FALSE
#  7     2       1        8 FALSE
#  8     2       1        9 FALSE
#  9     2       3       10 FALSE
# 10     2       2       15 TRUE 
# 11     2       2       16 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

My sincere apologies if I understood the question wrong. This does what I understand from the question:

```
 df$match = apply(df, 1, function(line) any(df$id == line[1] & 
                                            df$station == line[2] &
                                            df$timeslot == line[3] + 1))
```

The result then is

```
   id station timeslot match
1   1       1       13 FALSE
2   1       2       14 FALSE
3   1       3       20  TRUE
4   1       3       21 FALSE
5   1       2       24 FALSE
6   1       2       23  TRUE
7   2       1        8  TRUE
8   2       1        9 FALSE
9   2       3       10 FALSE
10  2       2       15  TRUE
11  2       2       16 FALSE
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for `line[2] == 2 & any(df$timeslot == line[3] + 1)`, but with the added wrinkle that the `any(df$timeslot == line[3] + 1)` needs to be evaluated only within the same `id`. I think you can make your method work with `line[2] == 2 & any(df$timeslot[df$id == line[1]] == line[3] + 1)`, but I didn't test.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas Thank you for the explanation. As the OP is happy with your solution I won't test as well but will upvote your's.